# Delete first two lines from txt files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-files

I need to delete the first two lines from a very large amount of txt files (about 10.000). I'm looking for a way to do this from the command line or through another semi-automatic procedure. Every file is different from the other, but they all contain some information on the first two lines that I need to get rid of.

Comment: Do the files contain empty lines that you want to retain?

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
  more +2 <  "%%~fa" > 2linesskipped.txt
  move /y 2linesskipped.txt "%%~fa"
)
```

without external tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think aguslr's answer looks good on a UNIX-derivative system, but I'm guessing since the tags are "cmd" and "batch-file" that you are on Windows. You can get `sed` for Windows in several places, for example in the [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) ports or more up-to-date ones via [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). But `find` is a built-in Windows program that is nothing like the find on UNIX-derivative systems. So you would probably want to replace the second half of the answer with a "for" command in Windows like:

```
for /r %a in (*.txt) do sed -i '1,2d' %a
```

Note that if you run this from a batch file you will want to use %%a instead of %a.

Comment: thank you! I am on windows right now, but I'll use the other unix machine to do this! very helpful :)